# reading dynamicaly added check box value

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, checkbox, dynamic

```
<head>
    <title>jQuery Add & Remove Dynamically Input Fields in PHP</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <h1>jQuery Add & Remove Dynamically Input Fields in PHP</h1>
    <form method="post" action="">
        <div class="form-group fieldGroup">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" name="phno[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter No" />
                <input type="checkbox" name="cdr[]" class="checkbox-inline cdr" />
                <input type="checkbox" name="caf[]" class="checkbox-inline caf" />
                <div class="input-group-addon">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-success addMore"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Add</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="SUBMIT" />
    </form>
    <!-- copy of input fields group -->
    <div class="form-group fieldGroupCopy" style="display: none;">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" name="phno[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter No" />
            <input type="checkbox" name="cdr[]" class="checkbox-inline cdr" />
            <input type="checkbox" name="caf[]" class="checkbox-inline caf" />
            <div class="input-group-addon">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-danger remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span> Remove</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-rc1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //group add limit
        var maxGroup = 10;

        //add more fields group
        $(".addMore").click(function() {
            if ($('body').find('.fieldGroup').length < maxGroup) {
                var fieldHTML = '<div class="form-group fieldGroup">' + $(".fieldGroupCopy").html() + '</div>';
                $('body').find('.fieldGroup:last').after(fieldHTML);
            } else {
                alert('Maximum ' + maxGroup + ' groups are allowed.');
            }
        });

        //remove fields group
        $("body").on("click", ".remove", function() {
            $(this).parents(".fieldGroup").remove();
        });

    });
    </script>
</body>
```

in the above code i get the check box values but not corresponding to the text field value

kindly help

i need out put as the data for eg
if i entered **abcd** then check one check box associated with it the the out i need is **abcd-value of checkbox clicked**
this will repetet up to the number of input group

Answer (score 0):

I assume "cdrtxt" is in the same node as ".cdr"?

Use .parent() on ".cdr"

```
$(document).on('click', '.cdr', function() {
     alert(1);
     $(this).parent().find('.cdrtxt').val("1");
});
```

Comment: actually my issue is on submitting i get the array of check box but i cant find wich one is corresponding to the text filed  named " phono "

Comment: this is not working on reading the value of cdrtxt it gives undefined

Comment: thats because ".val("1")" sets the value of "1". ".val()" will GET the value. https://api.jquery.com/val/

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with this one line of code:

```
$("this").find('.cdrtxt').val("1");
```

1. There is no such thing as `$("this")`. At least if you do not have a non-standard `<this>` tag in your HTML. When you want to refer to the node that received the event and wrap it in a jQuery object, you should use `$(this)` <-- no quotes.
2. There is no `cdrtxt` class in your HTML code.

The solution in your case is to search for the text input sibling of the clicked checkbox. Something like:

```
$(this).siblings('input[type=text]').val('something');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="phno[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter No" />
<input type="checkbox" name="cdr[]" class="checkbox-inline cdr" />
```

You **can not** properly associate the text input field values and checkbox values, using this naming scheme.

Text fields *always* cause an entry in the form submission data set, even if they are empty - checkboxes don’t, they only create one if they actually where checked.

If you had the above combination of fields four times, but you only checked the first and third checkbox, then you would get `$_POST['phno']` as an array of four text values, indexed from 0 to 3, and `$_POST['cdr']` would contain only *two* checkbox values (you did not specify one here explicitly, so those checkboxes would submit the value `on`), indexed with 0 and 1.

Based on those indexes, it is impossible to tell now, *which* of those checkboxes where checked. If you had checked the third and fourth instead, you would *still* get those values under the indexes `0` and `1`.

You need to specify the index upfront here:

```
<input type="text" name="phno[0]" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter No" />
<input type="checkbox" name="cdr[0]" class="checkbox-inline cdr" />
```

and that `0` needs to become `1` for the next set, and so on.

*Then* the checked checkboxes would get an index that corresponds to that of the text field.

There would still be “holes” in the indexes in `$_POST['cdr']` - if you checked the first (index 0) and fourth (index 3) one, then `$_POST['cdr'][0]` and `$_POST['cdr'][3]` would be set afterwards.
But if you loop over `$_POST['phno']`, which contains all indexes from 0 to 3, then you can use that index value to check if the corresponding index in `$_POST['cdr']` is set.

So you will have to modify your JavaScript part, that simply “clones” those existing rows, so that it sets the proper fields names, including the index.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with checkbox is that if it is not checked then it is not posted with the form. If you check a checkbox and post a form you will get the value of the checkbox in the $_POST variable , if it's unchecked no value will be assigned to the $_POST variable. So as to know which checkbox is checked assign a distinct value to it.This code might solve your problem

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

if(isset($_POST['checkbox'])){
echo 'Checkbox: ';
print_r($_POST['checkbox']);
}



if(isset($_POST['text'])){
$text=$_POST['text'];
echo 'Textbox: ';
print_r($text);

}
}
  ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="tests.php">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" class="check"  value="1">
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" class="check"  value="2">
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" class="check"  value="3">
<br>
<input type="text" name="text[]" class="text">
<br>

<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
<button id="add">ADD</button>
</body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
$('#add').on('click',function()
{
var breaks="<br>"
var checkbox="<br>";
var textbox="<br><input type='text' name='text[]' class='text'>";
var check_length=$('.check').length;

console.log(check_length);
for(var i=check_length+1;i<check_length+4;i++)
{   
    checkbox=checkbox+"<input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' class='check' value='" + i + "'><br>";
    

}
$('input[type="text"]').last().after(checkbox,textbox);
});
    });
</script>

</html>
```